# Map of an array in a functional component and access to a specific object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

```
function TypeArticleOne(props) {
let apiData = props.apiData;
const [ therapists, setTherapists ] = useState(apiData.topProfiles.therapists);
const [speciality, setSpeciality]= useState('ABA');
const [pageLoading, setPageLoading]= useState(true);

const topProfilesUrl = 'therapists/top/profiles'

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(speciality);
    getTopTherapists();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

}, []);

const getTopTherapists = () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    loadTopTherapists();

};

const loadTopTherapists = () => {
    console.log("second");
    props.actions.reqGetTherapistsTopProfiles({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${topProfilesUrl}`
    })
};

useEffect(() => {

    if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
        const therapistsLoad = apiData.topProfiles.therapists;
        setPageLoading(false);
        setTherapists([therapists].concat(therapistsLoad));
    }
    }, []);
```

How to map an array in a functional component? I want to map the therapists array from the functional component above. React is suggesting me to use UseRef(), because I have a functional component and I am using hooks, but it's not clear for me.
I call the therapists in an array from an database and I need to map them to render in a card, inside a functional component. For now I can access the array elements, but I need to access some specific parameters of the objects. Could you help me guys?

```
const renderTherapists = (props) => {
    const items = props.therapists.map( (t, idx) => (
        <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
    ))

    return (
        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            { items }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring a const, it is better to directly map the `props` like this:

```
const RenderTherapists = props => {
    return (
        <div className="therapist-list">
         { props.therapists.map((t, idx) => {
               return <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
         })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RenderTherapists;
```